# Use a bash variable in jenkins build job

Tags: jenkins

Im trying to use a variable created in a bash ("nombre" variable) and use it in a to trigger to another job with this parameter, as you can see i tried with "env.nombre":

```
stages{
    stage('PART1'){
        steps{
        cleanWs()
        git credentialsId: 'ssh-git-access', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:XXXX/XXXXX.git'
        script {
        sh '''
        nombre=$(cat /home/user/nombre.txt)
        echo $nombre
        '''
        ///THIS ECHO PRINT "HELLO"
        }   
    }     
}
stage('PART2'){
    steps{
        //ERROR HERE
        echo env.nombre
        build job: 'JOB_2', parameters: [string(name: 'nombre', value: env.nombre)]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried with this:

```
        environment {
            TRABAJO_NAME=env.nombre 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer me.

When i use sh directive, a new instance of shell (most likely bash) is created. As usual Unix processes, it inherits the environment variables of the parent.  When my script sets an environment variable, the environment of bash is updated. Once your script ends, the bash process that ran the script is destroyed, and all its environment is destroyed with it.

```
     def script_output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''
     #!/bin/bash
     nombre=$(cat /home/user/nombre.txt)
     echo $nombre   
     ''')
     script_output = script_output.trim()
     VAR_NAME = script_output
     //USING VARIABLE IN 'bash enviroment'
     echo "VAR_NAME is ${VAR_NAME}"
     //USING VARIABLE IN 'jenkins enviroment'
     echo  VAR_NAME
```

I dont know if its a optimal way to do it. Let me know if someone have another way.

Comment: Another way to do it:
VAR_NAME= sh(script: "echo Do something ", returnStdout: true).trim()